# Range of contour plot for polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

```
ContourPlot[-8 a^2 x + 9 x^2 - 12 x^3 + 4 x^4 == 
  0, {a, -.6, .6}, {x, -1, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, x}, x > 1*^-16]]
```

I am not getting how to set the desire range in this plot.
The required range is shown in this attached figure.

[image: Required range]

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me (v11.0):

[image]